# Android: How to handle the event of Portrait to Reverse Portrait and Landscape to Reverse Landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

When the screen orientation changed between (Reverse) Landscape and (Reverse) Portrait, the onCreate method of Activity would always be called. But when the screen orientation changed only between Landscape and Reverse Landscape or between Portrait and Reverse Portrait, the onCreate method even onResume method of Activity would not be called!

How to detect the event about reversing screen orientation?

If I use

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

and

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

No mater how I change the screen orientation, the onCreate method and onResume method of Activity would not be called, so that the views' positions on Activity are very weird. So, I prefer the solution about "how to detect the reversing screen orientation event" not to use configChanges.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method screenOrientationDidReverse:. when device only reverse the orientation, this method will be called. so... override the method!

Comment: how to use screenOrientationDidReverse? there is no reference to this function in the sdk.